# What are the difference in delay times of the basic AND, OR, NOT, NAND, NOR, XOR, XNOR gates?

Tags: logic, delay, circuit

1-1 What are the difference in delay times of the basic logic gates?

I found that NAND and NOR gates are preferred in digital circuit design for shorter delay time and that AND and OR gates might even be implemented with NOT and NAND/NOR gates.

1-2 Are there set or known difference in delay time between AND, OR, NOT gates?

Comment: what foundry and process?

Comment: what did the cell library vendor tell you when you asked?

Comment: When you build for a particular foundry/process you will directly or indirectly have access to this so that you can do timing closure and determine what clock rate you can run based on longest combinational paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how these different gates are constructed you can see some of the reasons for differences. An inverter consists of one pull-up transistor and one pull down transistor. This is the simplest gate and is therefore potentially the fastest. A NAND has two pull-down devices in series and two pull-up transistors in parallel. The NOR is basically the opposite of the NAND. And yes: AND is usually just NAND + inverter.

The on resistance of a path will be higher with two transistors in series (making it slower), and the number of transistors connected to a single node will increase the captive load (making it slower). You can make things faster by using larger transistors (with lower on resistance) but that increases the load of whatever cell is driving it, which slows that cell down.

It is a big optimization problem which you probably shouldn't try to solve yourself. That is what the EDA tools are for.

Answer (score 2):

For a typical fpga (LUT-based logical elements) there's no difference at all.
Single cell can implement a complex function based on its resulting truth table, and multiple expressions might be folded into single cell, so you wouldn't even find individual and/or/not "gates".

It might be different for ASIC, I don't know. But in a typical fpga you don't have gates, there are ram-based lookup tables, implementing complex functions of its inputs - 4-6 inputs, not just 2.

You'll find that in a big enough design the routing costs are much higher than delays in a single logical cell.

Answer (score 0):

Like most answers in life, it depends. There are many ways to build each type of logic gate and different types of transistors can be used to make each type of gate. You can build all gates from multiple universal gates like NAND and NOR. So the other gates would have a larger delay time. BJT transistors will have a larger delay than MOFET transistors. You can also use Schottky transistors to reduce delays compared to BJT. If you use an IC there are lots of components within the chip, some which may reduce delays and some that may increase delays. So you really have to compare what you are working with. Here is a video that shows the design of logic gates at the transistor level. https://youtu.be/nB6724G3b3E